# special condition in average cost function

Tags: calculus

written here that absolute minimum of a cost function will occur at it's critical point when $\overline {C}'(x)=0$
since $\overline {C}(x)=\frac {C(x)} {x}$
thus, the derivative is 
$$\overline {C}'(x) = \frac {xC'(x) - C(x)} {x^2}$$
in this case Marginal cost(derivative of main function) will equal to Average cost (function at x / x)

but i don't have idea how to stomach this. i mean if this phenomenon is occurs at critical point doesn't it mean Marginal cost(first derivative) is equal to zero at this point?(since x is critical points)
and above function will turn into 
$$0= \frac {0 - C(x)} {x^2}$$ and it will force $C(x)$ to become zero , and this don't make any sense, i hope someone tell me where did i go wrong

Comment: Marginal cost is the derivative of cost function. You require the derivative of **average** cost function to be $0$.

Comment: sorry i still confused , please tell me it's connection in critical points , since some case of extrema occurs in it (critical points)

Comment: The minimum average cost occurs when the derivative of **average cost function** equals zero, as you have written. This happens when the marginal cost, which is the derivative of the **cost function** and not the average cost function, equals the average cost function.

Comment: Your doubt arises because you are confusing the derivative of the average cost function with the derivative of the cost function (marginal cost function).

Comment: The phenomena occurs at the critical point of $\bar C(x)=\frac{C(x)}x$ and not $C(x)$, so there is no requirement for $C'(x)$ to be zero.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thank you! your last comment was brilliant!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum *average* cost occurs when $\bar C'(x)=0$ i.e. when the marginal cost $C'(x)$, which is the derivative of the *cost* function and not the *average cost* function, equals the average cost $\bar C(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $C'(x)$ and $\overline{C}'(x)$ are not the same functions. $\overline{C}'(x)$ = $0$ = $ xC'(x) - C(x)$. if you just want to find absolute minimum of cost function then you can solve $C'(x) = 0$ to find x.